# Problema al iniciar sesión, password_verify() no funciona

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un problema al iniciar sesión.
Tengo dos tipos de usuarios, cada uno se crea en momentos diferentes, pero en la misma tabla 'usuario', diferenciadolo por el id_rol.

El primero se crea asi

```
$this->db->set('Tie_ruc_dni', $Tie_ruc_dni);
            $this->db->set('Tie_Tipo', $Tie_Tipo);
            $this->db->set('Tie_Nombre', $Tie_Nombre);
            $this->db->set('Tie_RazonSocial', $Tie_RazonSocial);
            $this->db->set('Tie_Subdominio', $Tie_Subdominio);

            $this->db->insert('tienda');

            $Tie_IdTienda = $this->db->insert_id();

            //registro tabla usuario
            $this->db->set('Per_IdPersona', $Per_IdPersona);
            $this->db->set('Usu_Correo', $Per_Correo);
            $this->db->set('Usu_Clave', password_hash($Usu_Clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
            $this->db->set('Rol_IdRol', 2);
            $this->db->set('Tie_IdTienda', $Tie_IdTienda);

            $this->db->insert('usuario');
```

El segundo asi:

```
//registro tabla usuario
            $this->db->set('Per_IdPersona', $Per_IdPersona);
            $this->db->set('Usu_Correo', $Per_Correo);
            $this->db->set('Usu_Clave', password_hash($Usu_Clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
            $this->db->set('Rol_IdRol', 4);

            $this->db->insert('usuario');
```

Cuando inicio sesión, solo puedo ingresar como usuario tipo 4, en cambio,  con el usuario tipo 2, el password_verify() siempre resulta false, asi la contraseña sea correcta.

Esta es mi función para comparar

```
function usuario_login($Usu_Correo, $Usu_Clave)
        {
            $this->db->select('Usu_Clave');
            $this->db->from($this->nombre_tabla);
            $this->db->where('Usu_Correo', $Usu_Correo);

            $hash = $this->db->get()->row('Usu_Clave');

            return $this->verificar_clave_hash($Usu_Clave, $hash);
        }
```

```
function verificar_clave_hash($Usu_Clave, $hash)
        {
            return password_verify($Usu_Clave, $hash);
        }
```

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, trata de no publicar tu código con imagenes.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que le veo al código es que cuando haces el login, no aparece por ningún lado que le hagas el `password_hash()` a lo que el usuario escribe en el login.

Por lo que parece que estás comparando una contraseña sin hash con una que tienes en la base de datos ya con hash.

Necesitas hacer algo así para hashear la clave que introduce el usuario.

```
function verificar_clave_hash($Usu_Clave, $hash)
{
   $Usu_Clave = password_hash($Usu_Clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
   return password_verify($Usu_Clave, $hash);
}
```

Para ver si las contraseñas son iguales puedes añadir el `die;` para parar la ejecución de la función e imprimir los valores.

```
function verificar_clave_hash($Usu_Clave, $hash)
{
    $Usu_Clave = password_hash($Usu_Clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    echo $Usu_Clave . "<br>";
    echo $hash;
    die;
    return password_verify($Usu_Clave, $hash);
}
```

Comment: Tengo entendido que la función password_verify('12345', $hash), verifica la contraseña, con el hash, la cual, la estos trayendo de la base de datos. es decir, no seria necesario hashear la clave que introduce el usuario

Comment: Ese mismo codiugo, en otros proyectos si me funciona, y no sé, a que se debe, que ahora no me funcione